# Estimation of difficulty - measuring the volume of dust particles in the tank

Tags: python, machine-learning, image-recognition

my goal is just to get an expert estimation of how difficult a project described below could be.
I work in a company that produces chemicals (phosphates) in a form of powder. We store the powder in tanks (500m3 volume approx., 3 meters radius, 17 meters high). Our problem for many years has been that we have not been able to measure how much powder there is in the tank in a specific moment. This is mainly due to physical properties of powder (liquids would be easy to measure). When the powder is produced and put into the tank, it is hill-shaped, when the powder is getting out of the silo to be packed, a pit forms in the middle. I attached an image for better imagination.
[image: Tanks]
I got an idea if we could place a camera on the top of the tank, take some photos of different amounts and shapes of powder in the tank (and weigh the powder each time for these samples) and let the machine learning algorithm estimate the amount (in tons) of powder in the future. As far as I know there is no technology suitable for weighing the powder in a tank with constant in- or outflow of material (either its super expensive or very inaccurate).

So I would like to ask:

1. Do you think it would work?
2. How difficult would it be to write the code? I know some basic python programming and I am on an "intermediate" level in VBA. But I read several articles about image recognition and it does not seem so hard.
3. Estimation of how many samples (photo of a shape and its weight) we would need to teach the algorithm make a useful estimation?

Thanks for your opinions

Comment: ML usually works against actual right-hand side (y) variables. If it is impractical to find the actual weight, then I don't see how you can train or test your ML.

Comment: @rajah9 I think point number 3 would suggest that they do in fact have/plan to have the actual weights.

Comment: @k-venkatesan Exactly. We can find the actual weight ad hoc, it is just very time-consuming. That's why I would like to train a ML. If I could get some useful results with 50 and less training samples (photo + actual weight measured "the old way"), that would be great. If I needed 500+, it would not be worth it. I have no experince, so I am just asking for opinions :)

Comment: Just to make it clear: You are going to estimate the weights, which will be your RHS. You then want to create a ML model to estimate the estimates. If this is the case, then a couple more questions for you. How will you know if your ML model works? What kind of error is acceptable to you?

Comment: @rajah9 I will not estimate the weights, actually I will know the exact weights for all the samples = photos taken. I will take the photo and tell the staff to weigh the content of the tank. It just takes too long so I want to teach the algorithm to estimate the weight of the powder for me for the future based on the data (photos+exact weights of different situations). I dont know about the error. +-5% of actual volume is OK I guess

Answer (score 1):

It's certainly not an unreasonable idea. To answer your questions:

1. This depends on whether there is indeed a perceivable difference between the images. If two images look near-identical but their weights are different, then this is unlikely to work (note that it is possible that the computer detects differences that you might not, so don't dismiss it right away).
2. You will need to learn some basics of machine learning before you get started (your Python knowledge will help), but most of you're learning will likely be while working on the project. I would recommend the [Kaggle courses](https://www.kaggle.com/learn/overview) for you.
3. This is not easy to estimate - it depends heavily on the variation within your data, and the complexity of your model. I just noticed you added a comment mentioning that you'd ideally like to use less than 50 images - that is very likely to be nowhere near enough. The 500+ you fear is more than likely to be the case. However, keep in mind that the number of pictures used in training is not necessarily the number of pictures you'll have to take - through [data augmentation](https://nanonets.com/blog/data-augmentation-how-to-use-deep-learning-when-you-have-limited-data-part-2/) (such as flipping, rotating, flipping+rotating and other techniques), you can increase the number of images in your dataset.